# Xcode Swift CoreData Having Issues saving and calling Data

Tags: swift, core-data, save, fetch

So in my app it is a multi-viewcontroller tutorial. Walks a person through building a character in a roleplaying game. I got the first bit to create the record and I tried to use other projects I worked on to save the data and call the data. Now when I have dealt with CoreData I only have dealt with Strings. I am not sure how much is different when calling the data.

So first thing the user does insert the character number. Then they pick their mode, then their ability scores, then their races and so on. So when the user gets to the ViewController with the character number, a character number is pre-generated for them and they can change it if need be. They hit continue and then it creates the record. When they get to the ModeViewController, they have 2 buttons, core or standard. When they pick the button it is supposed to call the record based on the character number then update the record with the chosen mode.
Here is the code for ModeViewController:

```
    // Passed in variables from other ViewControllers
    var characterNumber = 0

    let managedObjectContext = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext


@IBAction func standardBtn(_ sender: Any)
    {
        let pred = NSPredicate(format: "(name = %@)", "characterNumber")
        print("Character Numeber: ", characterNumber)

        let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<Characters>(entityName: "Characters")
        fetchRequest.predicate = pred

        do
        {
            let fetchedEntities = try self.managedObjectContext.fetch(fetchRequest as! NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>) as! [Characters]

            // Character Information
            fetchedEntities.first?.mode = "standard"

            performSegue(withIdentifier: "mode", sender: nil)
        }
        catch
        {
            // Do something in response to error condition
            let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Did Not Save", message:
                "Your information did not save. \nIf this problem keeps occuring, contact the developer", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
            alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default,handler: nil))

            self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }

        do
        {
            try self.managedObjectContext.save()
        }
        catch
        {
            // Do something in response to error condition
        }
    }
```

In CoreData
Entity: Characters
Attribute: characternumber (int16)

Now the other button for core has the same exact code except instead of saving standard it saves core.

Here is the code I have that is supposed to call the data based on the character data:

```
    // Passed in variables from other ViewControllers
    var characterNumber = 0

    // Other variables
    let managedObjectContext = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext
    var mode: [NSManagedObject] = []
    var selectededMode = ""


   let entityDescription = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "Characters", in: managedObjectContext)

    let request: NSFetchRequest<Characters> = Characters.fetchRequest()
    request.entity = entityDescription

    // Supposed to call the record based on characternNumber
    let pred = NSPredicate(format: "(characternumber = %@)", "characterNumber")
    request.predicate = pred

    do
    {
        var results = try managedObjectContext.fetch(request as! NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>)

        print("results = ", results)

        if results.count > 0
        {
            let match = results[0] as! NSManagedObject

            print("match= ", match)

            selectededMode = (match.value(forKey: "mode") as? String)!
            print("Mode: ",  selectededMode)
        }
        else
        {
            selectededMode = "empty"
            print("Mode: ",  selectededMode)
        }
```

Now I think that my main issue is that the data is not saving the mode I select into coredata. Again I have only dealt with Strings and now venturing into to integers.

Create the actual record:

```
@IBAction func savingSocNum(_ sender: Any)
{
    if societyNumberTxt.text == ""
    {
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "No Society Number", message: "You have not entered your Society Nmber.\nPlease enter your Society Number to advance", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: nil))
        self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    else
    {
        let entity = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "Characters", in: managedObjectContext)!
        let entity1 = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "Societynumber", in: managedObjectContext)!

        let cnumber = NSManagedObject(entity: entity, insertInto: managedObjectContext)
        let snumber = NSManagedObject(entity: entity1, insertInto: managedObjectContext)

        let newCharNum = Int(characterNumberTxt.text!)!


        guard let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate else {
            return
        }

        let managedContext = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext

        //2
        let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSManagedObject>(entityName: "Societynumber")

        do {
            societyNum = try managedContext.fetch(fetchRequest)

            // Fetchs data from Characters
            let entityDescription = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "Societynumber", in: managedObjectContext)

            let request: NSFetchRequest<Societynumber> = Societynumber.fetchRequest()
            request.entity = entityDescription

            var results = try managedObjectContext.fetch(request as! NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>)

            if societyNum.isEmpty
            {
                print("empty")
            }
            else
            {
                print("not empty")
            }

        } catch let error as NSError {
            print("Could not fetch. \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
        }



        snumber.setValue(societyNumberTxt.text, forKeyPath: "societynumber")
        cnumber.setValue(newCharNum, forKey: "characternumber")

        do
        {
            try managedObjectContext.save()
            characters.append(cnumber)
        }
        catch let error as NSError
        {
            print("Could not save. \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
        }

        performSegue(withIdentifier: "continue", sender: nil)
    }
}
```

Comment: Where do you insert (create) any managedObjects?

Comment: Assuming that I answered your question, I have updated the answer. The last bit of code I added is where I create the record. I know that much works.